# How to match the 2 last numbers of an IP adress?

Tags: regex, bash

i don't know what i'm missing ^^

I'm on bash script, i tested it with https://regex101.com/

Here is some ip adress:

```
192.168.23.84
192.168.112.34
192.168.43.227
```

And i want to match only the numbers that are not by group of 3, i've tried:

```
\.([0-9]{2})\.|\.([0-9]{1})\.|\.([0-9]{2})$|\.([0-9]{1})$
```

I don't know why i'm not matching the two last numbers, Is there a better solution ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? Only the last two numbers of an IP if there's exactly 2 numbers after the last dot? If that's the case, you're looking for [`(?<=\.)\d{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/9SJ1wG/1/)

Comment: whatever you want to accomplish, please don't call these (with bytes like 897 or 345) IP addresses. The bytes can only be [0-255], including broadcast addresses and stuff.

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: There are thousands of regex IP questions and thousands of answers. This is a duplicate.

Comment: Nic Reed: "i want to match only the numbers that are not by group of 3"

Comment: Michał Krzysztof Feiler: It was just an exemple don't be so rude for that. Anyway i've update it

Comment: Toto: That why i have the "bash" tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(\d{1,2})\.|\.(\d{1,2})\.|\.(\d{1,2})$
```

You've got 3 cases : 1|2 digits after the start followed by a dot, 1|2 digits betweens dots, 1|2 digit after a dot at the end of the line.

With this solution you'll have 3 groups and you won't be able to known which part for the middle group has not 3 digits. If you want 4 groups use this one :

```
(?:^(\d{1,2})\.)|(?:^\d{3}\.(\d{1,2})\.)|(?:\.(\d{2})$)|(?:\.(\d{2})\.\d{2,3})
```

Edit : https://regex101.com/r/eAc8XX/1

Be aware that I'm not looking for a valid IPv4 with theses regex.